# Compile error after a modification

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to modify a spreadhseet as it seems to eventually have some errors.
The code below is the current one:

```
Range("DP2").Value = "=IF(RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)<0,60+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2),RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)) + RC[-1]"
```

The problem is that the values the logical is looking at are time (HHMM) and it takes the right 2 (MM) and subtract from another time (MM), and where the value is below zero, it just adds 60 assuming the first time just one hour ahead (which is true) but the problem is I have observations where the difference is more than an hour (2 hrs, 3 hrs, etc.) e.g. 1110 and 0830, hence adding only 60 will not do the right calculation.
I've written this code:

```
  IF(RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)<=0, IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=1,60+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2), IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=2,120+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2), IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=3,180+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2),RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2))))) + RC[-1]"
```

This one is supposed to look at the hour section of the time value (Left 2,, HH), and accordingly decide whether to add 60, 120 or 180. 
But VBA just won't accept the code saying it's a compile error!

Answer (score 0):

You've exceeded the number of characters per line in the VBE, break up your string on separate lines like so:

```
Range("D2").Value = "IF(RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]" & _
"=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)<=0, IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=1,60+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2), IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=2,120+RIGHT(IF" & _
"(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP" & _
"(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2), IF(LEFT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-LEFT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2)=3,180+RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2),RIGHT(IF(R1C[-110]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-110],0)),2)-RIGHT(IF(R1C[-111]=RC7,VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,32,0),VLOOKUP(RC4,Services!C1:C254,146+R1C[-111],0)),2))" & _
"))) + RC[-1]"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this have solved the error, but it have introduced a new error which didn't happen before (the old code).
It says there is a mismatch and when I go for debug it highlights this:

    line_txt = line_txt & nd_str & ", "

I'm surprised because this was working fine on the previous code.

Comment: In which case you will need to try and debug the issue, and if you don't get anywhere it will need to be a separate question.

Comment: Oh Ok no problem.

Thank you very much!